# Can you customize dock icons and labels?

Tags: macos, dock, icon, shortcut

I have several virtual machines shortcutted on my dock. By default these are all named "VirtualBoxVM" and have the same icon, it's difficult for me to tell them apart. I'd like to give them all at least a different name, hopefully also a different icon.

My question is, ***can you customize dock icons and labels?***

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Icons

Icons on the Dock are pulled from the icon of the item. You can change the icon of the item using the Get Info page.

1. Get the icon/image that you want to use for the icon on the Dock and open it in Preview.
2. Press ⌘A to select all of the image and ⌘C to copy it.
3. ⌘-click the item in the Dock to open its location in Finder.
4. Open the Get Info window with ⌘I (or right-click → Get Info).
5. Select the icon in the top-left of the Get Info window and press ⌘V to paste.
6. If the icon in the Dock does not update, log out and back in, or restart the Dock with `killall -HUP Dock`.

#### Names

The name of the item on the Dock is pulled from the name of the item itself. You can rename the item by ⌘-clicking on the item in the Dock and renaming it from Finder.